# AS3 Update Variable Reports Null.. in a pattern

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a space game in AS3 - I have an enemy class named EnemyShip.

I've already registered the Event.ENTER_FRAME and it works correctly - the problem is that my variable, rowXY of type Array, reports both null and a non-null value.. in a pattern.

How can I keep this from happening (or is there an easier way to animate the ships to move in Flash Professional?).

The pattern is as follows:
[image: Error pattern]

### EnemyShip:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class EnemyShip extends Sprite
    {
        internal var id:int;
        internal var rowOrder:int;
        internal var rowXY:Array;
        private var dirUp:Boolean = false;

        public function EnemyShip()
        {
            // add event listeners
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);    
        }

        private function update(e:Event):void
        {
            moveUpAndDown();

            trace(rowXY);

            function moveUpAndDown():void
            {
                if (dirUp)
                    y -= C.ENEMY_SPEED;
                else
                    y += C.ENEMY_SPEED;
            }
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
        {
            // get row XY
            if (rowOrder == 1)
                rowXY = C.ENEMY_ROW_1;

            if (rowOrder == 2)
                rowXY = C.ENEMY_ROW_2;

            if (rowOrder == 3)
                rowXY = C.ENEMY_ROW_3;

            // set XY position
            x = rowXY[0];
            y = rowXY[1];

            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        }

        internal function destroy():void
        {
            rowOrder = null;
            rowXY = null;

            // remove event listeners
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

            // remove from display list
            parent.removeChild(this);

        }

    }

}
```

### C.as (Constants):

```
package
{
    // C stands for constants

    public class C
    {
        // ship constants
        public static const FIRE_DELAY:int = 500; // milliseconds

        // laser constants
        public static const LASER_SPEED:int = 30;
        public static const POINTS_KILL:int = 10;

        // mcScore constants
        public static const SCORE_LOC_X:Number = 345;
        public static const SCORE_LOC_Y:Number = -120;

        // enemy ship constants
        public static const ENEMY_ROW_1:Array = [485, -45];
        public static const ENEMY_ROW_2:Array = [485, 25];
        public static const ENEMY_ROW_3:Array = [485, 95];
        public static const ENEMY_SPEED:int = 5; // 5 pixels
        public static const ENEMY_Y_MIN:int = -10;
        public static const ENEMY_Y_MAX:int = 10;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `rowOrder`? My guess is that's not getting set properly for some instances of `EnemyShip`, causing `rowXY` to not get set in `onAddedToStage()`.

Comment: @Cadin My bad - here is a picture of the code: http://prntscr.com/9cdn1p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Solution

It was to my knowledge that the event Event.ENTER_FRAME was only passed to objects on the stage, but this is not true.

The problem was in my EnemyShip class' constructor method - the ENTER_FRAME event was being listened to by both on- and off-stage instances - the off-stage instances had not been assigned a rowXY (this happens in the event ADDED_TO_STAGE).

Old Code:

[image: Old Code]

New Code:

[image: New Code]

**So what's the lesson to be learned here?**

Event.ENTER_FRAME happens no matter if the object is displayed or not.

Comment: Good for you you learned something but you should learn more than just that: NO EVENT LISTENERS STOP WORKING MAGICALLY IN AS3 EVER. And I mean ever, ever, ever. There will never be a case when a event will stop working just cos you are not using an object anymore, if you don't remove the listener yourself, it will still be there and will still fire until you do something about it.

Comment: Haha, I know that, of course - hence my destroy() methods. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to animate using Flash Professional, I would take advantage of their built in [Motion Tween](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/motion-tween-animation.html) feature. You could also animate the ship in your code by taking advantage of the [Tween](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3tweenclass/) class.

Comment: Thank you for the links! I feel that these may come in handy some day ;)

Comment: "or is there an easier way to animate the ships to move in Flash Professional?" Why not today? :)

Comment: You're right - I'll start using Motion Tween in my next projects (from reading about Motion Tween from Adobe Docs, it stands out as a great feature).

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the behavior that you've got using this `for` loop ( you can get the same result by instantiating 3 objects and insert 3 others directly to the stage ) :

```
for(var i:int = 1; i < 7; i++){
    var enemy:EnemyShip = new EnemyShip();
        enemy.rowOrder = i;
    addChild(enemy);
}
```

here we can see very clear that where `i` is 4, 5 or 6, `rowOrder` will be `null` which also will fire some #1009 errors for all the instances which has the `rowOrder` greater that 3 from this line :

```
x = rowXY[0];
```

So to avoid that, you can, for example, restrict the value of `rowOrder` to be between 1 and 3, like this, for example :

```
enemy.rowOrder = 1 + int(Math.random()*3);
```

you can also set that value inside the `EnemyShip` class itself.

...

Hope that can help.

Comment: While your for loop supports your answer, it isn't precise in the code it contains in the code block. Here a picture of the code (edited a little) http://prntscr.com/9cdn1p . Thank you for your help, though - I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you posted you have this code:

```
if(rowOrder > 3)
    rowOrder = 0;
```

But when you check `rowOrder` in `onAddedToStage()` you don't have a case for 0 -- only 1, 2, or 3. So `rowXY` never gets set when `rowOrder` is 0.

Either change that code to set `rowOrder` to 1 instead of 0, or change your other code to be zero indexed.